# Extract nested JSON from R dataframe without knowing keys

Tags: json, r, dplyr, purrr

I am trying to extract JSON from a TSV column. The difficulty is the JSON is shallowly nested, and the key values may not be present in every row.

I have a minimal example to illustrate my point.

```
  df <- tibble(index = c(1, 2),
   data = c('{"json_char":"alpha", "json_list1":["x","y"]}', 
         '{"json_char":"beta", "json_list1":["x","y","z"], "json_list2":["a","b","c"]}'))
```

The desired result:

```
  df <- tibble::tibble(index = list(1, 2),
        json_char = list("alpha", "beta"),
        json_list1 = list(list("x","y"), list("x","y","z")),
        json_list2 = list(NA, list("a","b","c")))
```

After a fair amount of experimentation, I have this function:

```
extract_json_column <- function(df) {
  df %>%
    magrittr::use_series(data) %>% 
    purrr::map(jsonlite::fromJSON) %>% 
    purrr::map(purrr::simplify) %>% 
    tibble::enframe() %>% 
    tidyr::spread("name", "value") %>%
    purrr::flatten_dfr()
}
```

Which gives me the following error: `Error in bind_rows_(x, .id) : Argument 2 must be length 3, not 7`.

The first row sets the number of parameters for the rest of dataframe. Is there anyway to avoid that behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your function to the following. I hope this helps.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rjson)

extract_json_column <- function(df){
  df %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(data = map(data, fromJSON)) %>%
    split(.$index) %>%
    map(~.$data[[1]]) %>%
    map(~map_if(., function(x) length(x) != 1, list)) %>%
    map(as_data_frame) %>%
    bind_rows(.id = "index")
}

extract_json_column(df)
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  index json_char json_list1 json_list2
  <chr>     <chr>     <list>     <list>
1     1     alpha  <chr [2]>     <NULL>
2     2      beta  <chr [3]>  <chr [3]>
```